# Pika Amqps Connection: Connection attempt completed with AMQPConnectorAMQPHandshakeError: IncompatibleProtocolError

Tags: python, ssl, amqp, pika, python-pika

I am trying to use `pika` connect to a AMQPS-Service (to which I have no config access or a way to get the certificates).

Here's the code:

```
import pika
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import ssl

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username, password)

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
ssl_options=pika.SSLOptions(context)

params = pika.ConnectionParameters(
    host=url.hostname, 
    port=url.port, 
    credentials=credentials, 
    ssl_options=ssl_options
)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
channel = connection.channel() # start a channel
```

Everytime I try to execute this though, it fails with:

```
ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:AMQPConnector - reporting failure: 
AMQPConnectorAMQPHandshakeError: 
IncompatibleProtocolError: The protocol returned by the server is not supported: 
('StreamLostError: 
("Stream connection lost: SSLEOFError(8, \'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2633)\')",)',)
```

Unfortunately, I do not know which protocol is returned by the server.

Using `qpid-proton` with the `sasl_enabled: True` option set, it works without any issues.

```
from proton import Message
from proton.utils import BlockingConnection

conn = BlockingConnection(
    url,
    password=password,
    user=username,
    sasl_enabled=True,
)
```

However, I haven't found a way to do this with `pika`.

Comment: What AMQP version does the remote service support?

Comment: Hi there, it supports AMQP 1.0, SMF

Comment: So Pika only support 0.9.1 if I read that correctly?

Comment: According to the site (https://github.com/pika/pika) it supports 0.9.1 and so you cannot connect to a 1.0 endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess from reading the question and later comments the remote endpoint supports AMQP 1.0 and the Pika client appears to support only the 0.9.1 draft AMQP spec which would make the returned error sensible.  You'd need to use a client capable of using the ISO spec AMQP 1.0 standard

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; I just used the `pika.urlParameter` instead to force an SSL connection:

```
url_string = "amqps://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + host + ":" + str(port) + "/" + vhost
url_parameter = pika.URLParameters(url_string)
connection =  pika.BlockingConnection(url_parameter)
```